# SQL (Snowflake) - Create duplicate Records changing only a single Field after duplication

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, unpivot, union-all, lateral-join

I have a table that looks like below:

| ID | DATE_OPENED | DATE_CLOSED | STATUS | TREATMENT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-12-05 | 2022-12-05 | Notification | Control |
| 2 | 2022-11-24 | 2022-11-24V | Viewed | Control |
| 3 | 2022-12-11 | 2022-12-11 | Subjecting | Control |

I want to duplicate each record, but for each duplicate, change the Status field from what already exists in that record to that static string: "all" like below:

| ID | DATE_OPENED | DATE_CLOSED | STATUS | TREATMENT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-12-05 | 2022-12-05 | Notification | Control |
| 1 | 2022-12-05 | 2022-12-05 | ALL | Control |
| 2 | 2022-11-24 | 2022-11-24V | Viewed | Control |
| 2 | 2022-11-24 | 2022-11-24V | ALL | Control |
| 3 | 2022-12-11 | 2022-12-11 | Subjecting | Control |
| 3 | 2022-12-11 | 2022-12-11 | ALL | Control |

Is there an easy way to do this in SQL? Perhaps via a window function?

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY 1) = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easily with a `UNION ALL`, but using 'ALL' in place of the original Status value.

```
SELECT ID, DATE_OPENED, DATE_CLOSED,          STATUS, TREATMENT FROM tab
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, DATE_OPENED, DATE_CLOSED, 'ALL' AS STATUS, TREATMENT FROM tab
ORDER BY ID, STATUS DESC
```

**Note**: Last `ORDER BY` clause is optional.

Answer (score 1):

In Snowflake, I would recommend a lateral join to duplicate the rows:

```
select t.id, t.date_opened, t.date_closed,
    v.status, t.treatment
from mytable t
cross join lateral ( values (t.status), ('ALL') ) v(status)
```

Not only is the syntax neater; the real upside of this approach is efficiency, as it scans the table only once, as opposed to the `union all` solution, which scans twice.

Comment: This looks like a very interesting solution to learn from.